# when call query method on contentProvider the app crash?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 3 columns.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.android.home.contentprovidertut, PID: 24432
                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: Add code or there is nothing we can do

Comment: And your **FULL logcat** as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access a column that does not exist. This happens if you try to get the index of that column by string and misspell that string. For exampe if you have a column named `hello` and you write

```
String url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("hallo"));
```

this will fail.